# Changing the color of the text in a transparent div

Tags: css, html

Im trying to make a 960px, float left website and using black transperent divs with text in them. The problem is that the text has the same color as the div, but I want it to be white or at least not the same as the div. How can i do this?

This is my CSS for the moment, the problem is that position is set to relative, but I just want to use diferent divs and use "float: left". If I remove "position: relative" the transparent color of the div disappears.

```
  .content {
   position:relative;
   color:White;
   z-index:10;
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
   left: 365px;
   font-family: Arial;
   margin: 10px;
   top: 15px;
```

}

```
.background {
   position:absolute;
   border-radius: 10px;
   width:960px;
   height: 70px;
   background-color:Black;
   z-index:1;

   -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=50);
   opacity:.5;
   top: 80px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use transparent background instead with:

```
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The content inherits the opacity of your container. Explicitly set the opacity of the content to not be .5 but 1.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine, see the fiddle and tell me if it's working for you. I've changed the width to % but it works just as well on px, ijust wanted to remove the scrolling in the fiddle, and changed the `Color:White;` to `color:#fff;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/americanjoel/B53am/1/)